# Linear Regression vs Random Forest performance accuracy

Tags: python, data-science

If the dataset contains features some of which are Categorical Variables and some of the others are continuous variable Decision Tree is better than Linear Regression,since Trees can accurately divide the data based on Categorical Variables. Is there any situation where Linear regression outperforms Random Forest?

Answer (score 4):

There for sure have to be situations where Linear Regression outperforms Random Forests, but I think the more important thing to consider is the complexity of the model.

Linear Models have very few parameters, Random Forests a lot more. That means that Random Forests will overfit more easily than a Linear Regression.

Comment: I am doing a EDA at this moment,in my dataset I have 20 features and 8000 observations. Out of the 20 features,I have found 5 features which are mostly linked to the response. I have used Ordinary Least Squares and obtained Adjuster R square as 0.95. Could you please let me know whether Random Forest perform better than Linear Regression in this case?

Comment: @SouravSaha THAT is a question you should find the answer to by experiment. In my opinion, simple models should be tried first, more complex models should be judged by how well they perform compared to the simple models. So, what I am trying to say is, just try both.

Comment: Completely agree with @kutschkem that the only way to find the answer is by experiment! Machine learning is an empirical field where there are few set rules that let us say method x is always better than method y.

Answer (score 3):

Key advantages of linear models over tree-based ones are:

- they can extrapolate (e.g. if labels are between 1-5 in train set, tree based model will never predict 10, but linear will)
- could be used for anomaly detection because of extrapolation
- interpretability (yes, tree based models have feature importance, but it's only a proxy, weights in linear model are better)
- need less data to get good results
- have strong online learning implementations (Vowpal Wabbit), which is crucial to work with giant datasets with a lot of features (e.g. texts)